# Bubble sort only bring up one random number instead of sorting

Tags: c++, arrays, bubble-sort

Code:

```
void displayDesc(double inch[])
{
int i, j;
    int n = 12;
    double temp = 0.0;
    for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) 
      {
        if (inch[j] > inch[j+1]) 
        {
          temp = inch[j];
          inch[j] = inch[j+1];
          inch[j+1] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
cout << "Here is the Texas rainfall in 2020 in descending order: " << temp << endl;
}
```

The rest of the code runs like a dream but I've been through this a few times and it'll only print out one number, zero, or a random one. Can any of you tell me what's going on?

Comment: You need to loop through `inch[]` and print each one. You are only printing the last temp. Also `inch[j+1]` may reference a value outside of `inch` which is undefined behavior.

Comment: @doug: `inch[j+1]` is not out of `inch`, due to the `j < n-i-1` limit

Comment: @MooingDuck. Yeah, you're right. My error. It's just the `temp` issue`

Answer (score 2):

You need to print every element in inch[], as the `temp` variable you have is only the most recent one, not the whole array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void displayDesc(double inch[])
{
    int i, j;
    int n = 12;
    double temp = 0.0;
    for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
      {
        if (inch[j] > inch[j+1])
        {
          temp = inch[j];
          inch[j] = inch[j+1];
          inch[j+1] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
    cout << "Here is the Texas rainfall in 2020 in descending order: " << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {cout << inch[i] << " ";} //you need this line
}

int main()
{
    //sample data
    double x[] = {1, 2, 3, 4.6, 2.5, 3.9, 11.1, 6.8, 9.0, 0.5, 13.3, 5.4};
    displayDesc(x);
}
```

Sample output:

```
Here is the Texas rainfall in 2020 in descending order:
0.5 1 2 2.5 3 3.9 4.6 5.4 6.8 9 11.1 13.3
```